# Что за формат в теле запроса?

Tags: http, request

```
sign=8d8e38b764fde411ddc4a3de4d704507ea273493884c63f063e6685af3e0b9687e4439442bb792f1bdcb59b9c35490fc8d422f9328decdf1d4c8b5958cd13d9d
data=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
```

Пробовал конвертировать из Base64  в UTF-8 выдает не пойми что.

Comment: Да, очевидно это base64. Но закодированы в него некие двоичные данные, а не текст

Answer (score 0):

Это base64 с какими-от бинарными данными внутри.

```js
var sign = "8d8e38b764fde411ddc4a3de4d704507ea273493884c63f063e6685af3e0b9687e4439442bb792f1bdcb59b9c35490fc8d422f9328decdf1d4c8b5958cd13d9d"
var data = "OTQJVINli9pZaSxQUgKj0mTEgh3wq2Iao98uS4IehQ0+xVIhbY3NdtFeWbv5b1L+qKr5dtVACMY38JwxUNPnepJcR4+KDUpncqfY42hlngbWb1F3efgQd3H066+qSrVvcyl2VzMhk+RlSt6fNr0sfY98n9RmUbBrJWGxjq55yzRhVNedGKj3SGkBm6qeJ6eNyzzsbhqH5LYpHSeXBwt2haqK/bm1Zk0dTXxrVvEZn4WqYleROKiaEzxkJiNPOgvoeT6VmEHSTaaNk1sMn32rP5stGRK+1jdB8hdo+0EPp8lewRS82ma0kqbMoFNKUMRcjrrz0oGXRBktxZIChKI04dKa/8PRYGGLLOpe3NSobF2nQUULaHD37hIeHW6ISwxkKPJlQClqW3vb+fmzNgI0RqXASqYUN4wn/v/1bqg70Hdu4nhg+1HPRu4IgiwoaCmNQkL69gnSZ1ONjMLkzyGES6YjL7nv9hhAEJ4sIQiTO3N1hbaBJeRzbR4u2ICz7rrFiqFqtB6aOGPX4pPZN+vjP4F1DieRl82pcvqDdfGRKqy8oF+JRsWMsbJIjdj76zal05Vn5EacLu03m/ldKI6ZpkEXEIsEcudNvPauD43h4jvpS6bWP//2AATiKskDxTumypmt00UBm4mV+/sSb0dDFybC0dbNj63iceDoOuh2xxojfH2QDxyAy65d/T/7dafovzEk1L3BXKyV851U4M8dYbY+T4tB3haygixZ+KZXYyM="

console.log(atob(sign))
console.log(atob(data))
```